# embedded multiple instances of vert.x http server within a Java Spring framework program

Tags: vert.x

How can I embedded multiple instances of vert.x http server within a Java Spring framework program.

```
        vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertHttpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
```

how can I start the vertHttpServer with mulltiple vertx instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with how:

```
Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
HttpServer vertHttpServer1 = vertx.createHttpServer();
HttpServer vertHttpServer2 = vertx.createHttpServer();
vertHttpServer1.listen(8080);
vertHttpServer2.listen(8081);
```

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/spring-examples/spring-example/src/main/java/io/vertx/examples/spring/verticle/ServerVerticle.java

Note you'll need different ports for that.
The question is, why would you need two servers. One VertX server is concurrent enough to server all your requests. So unless you want to divide you application by ports, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want the sever instances listening to the same port. The reason I want multiple instances of vertx is that I have a legacy program that using ratpack http server, and lots of blocking call in the handlers. I want to replace the ratpack server with Vertx. And I found vertx blockingHandler is not working (always saying request has been read when trying get the request.body()).

Comment: Using `blockingHandler` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: This is wrong (need for 2 ports to split the traffic).